# What do these multiple dots mean in a complex statement?

Tags: java

I know little bit of `JAVA`. I sometimes able to understand the written code. So, while going through this piece of code, I saw there is red underline under one statement. I wanted to investigate how this error was coming. In eclipse you can easily navigate to classes, methods by pressing `Ctrl+mouse hover+click` what ever you want to see. But where you have error, you wont be able to navigate by pressing this combination.

How to read this statement:
`TestLogging.log((new StringBuilder("Exception encountered when quiting driver: ")).append(WebUIDriver.getWebUXDriver().getConfig().getBrowser().name()).append(":").append(ex.getMessage()).toString());`

Error at `.name()`

Comment: Ouuch!!

...minus 2...

Comment: a dot `.` calls the corresponding member method of the object. see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html

Comment: I knew that but how come `.getConfig()` and `.getBrowser()` are part of different classes. I dont even see reference calling these methods.

Comment: What do you mean by "I dont even see reference calling these methods"? `getConfig()` is a method of `WebUIDriver`, `getBrowser()` a method of the config of the `WebUIDriver`.... and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This technique is called [Method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining#Java)

Each method call retuns an object which is then in turn used to call another method which returns an other object and son on.

Here is how you can read it (Object types are only assumptions):

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Exception encountered when quiting driver: ");
 WebUXDriver w = WebUIDriver.getWebUXDriver();
 Config c = w.getConfig();
 Browser b = c.getBrowser();
 sb.append(b.name());
 sb.append(":");
 sb.append(ex.getMessage());
 String line = sb.toString();
 TestLogging.log(line);
```